# Redshift : Join the tables with like condition

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want table_A to join when the value in column_A matches with the part or full string in Column_B of Table B

```
Ex:

TableA: 
column_A
Denver
Chicago
Newyork
Dallas

TableB: 
Column_B
Chicago
Newyork, Dallas
$Denver

Expected Result
column_A    Column_B
Denver      $Denver
Chicago     Chicago
Newyork     Newyork, Dallas
Dallas      Newyork, Dallas
```

I am trying this -

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.Column_A LIKE '%' || b.Column_B || '%'
```

The above concat seems to work for single values but not where we have commas. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use the similar to operation. See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP).